# Soft spun vs ring spun

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference

"Now we are side by side on the sofa, a spun-soft blanket over us, because Desi had cranked up the air-conditioning so that it is autumn in July". Firstly, I'd like to ask if spun soft is the same as soft spun, because the latter is the only version I can find online.

Secondly, can somebody think of a reason why this adjective was chosen rather than ring spun, is there a notable difference?

Comment: What are you quoting

Comment: See "order of adjectives". "Soft" is an opinion, which precedes "spun", which describes the material of the blanket. Sounds weird if it's in a different order.

Comment: what is a "spun blanket",  If you spin a blanket, is it a spun blanket?

Comment: The hyphen means we need to understand "soft-spun" as a compound word.  With "soft" modifying "spun" to refer to the way in which the fibre is prepared.  Not as "a soft, spun blanket", which doesn't mean anything.  "Soft-spun" is a marketing term.

Comment: Thank you, @JamesK, for your elaborate answer - you answered all my questions.

Comment: Great writing, it ain't. The author is trying to avoid the word: cozy.

Comment: I agree, @Lambie. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ring-spun is (apparently) a technical term for a type of cotton that doesn't pill.

Soft-spun is a marketing phrase for any fabric that is soft to the touch.

The author probably isn't a specialist in fabric, but they have heard of a phrase like "soft-spun" or "spun soft" or something, and that is what they have used.  I don't see any deep meaning here, just an author looking for phrase, using the one that is more familiar, but getting it a bit mixed up.